# we are five we have three thousand four hundred fifty who are we?

Tags: riddle, mathematics, logical-deduction

we are five we three thousand four hundred fifty, who are we ?. Its a riddle like question but stranded with getting the answer for this question , am very  sure the answer will make me slap my head if i get help. it might be about things of our daily use or logic.

Comment: Please clarify your puzzle/ difficulty encountered. Should your question be excessively vague and cannot be interpreted, it will very likely get closed. Please help us so that we can help you. Thanks and happy puzzling ;)

Comment: yes thank you Omega Krypton . That is how the riddle is  i have no any other option about that , i guess you to can solve for me the problem i have figured out different answers but all in vein.thank you

Comment: rot13: ybbx ng gur cevzr snpgbef bs 3450

Comment: Jasen please translate to english

Comment: ATheart, when someone's message looks like giberish and starts by "rot13", it means he is using the simple rot13 algorithm to "code" his message, so that it's not readable at first glance. It's the only way the community found to hide their spoiling messages in comments, since we don't have access to the usual markups. Go to rot13.com and enter his message to be able to read it. (However, he could have made a comment, since he obviously found an answer, wether it's the correct one or not. It does check out, so I'll upvote him)

Answer (score 1):

> It could be a play on words. You are five different numbers (three, [a] thousand, four, [a] hundred and fifty).